# PHP can't access this objects value

Tags: php

If I do a print_r() statement to show me the content of my object it returns this:

```
stdClass Object ( [groupData] => {"global":["CoolPerson","Person"]} [permissionData] => {} )
```

How can I return the String "CoolPerson"?

I already tried the following:

```
$myObject['global'][0]
```

and

```
$myObject['groupData']['global'][0]
```

Comment: What is groupData?  A global, variable, string... etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `groupData` property of your object is a `JSON` string. You should try this:

```
json_decode($myObject->groupData)->global[0]
```